# Exporting contacts merged to households causes DB error version 4.6.8

Tags: issues, export, 4.6.8

Viewed contacts from a Smart Group and went to Export. Merged to household and tried with and without do-not-mail/deceased criteria.

Seems to work OK if I select a couple of fields, but if I do primary export it crashes to blank screen and leaves this in log:

```
$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -1 [message] => DB Error: unknown error [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.hash as `hash`, contact_a.source as `contact_source`, contact_a.first_name as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code as `sic_code`, contact_a.user_unique_id as `user_unique_id`, contact_a.employer_id as `current_employer_id`, contact_a.is_deleted as `contact_is_deleted`, contact_a.created_date as `created_date`, contact_a.modified_date as `modified_date`, contact_a.addressee_id as addressee_id, contact_a.addressee_display as addressee_display, contact_a.addressee_custom as addressee_custom, contact_a.email_greeting_id as email_greeting_id, contact_a.email_greeting_display as email_greeting_display, contact_a.email_greeting_custom as email_greeting_custom, contact_a.postal_greeting_id as postal_greeting_id, contact_a.postal_greeting_display as postal_greeting_display, contact_a.postal_greeting_custom as postal_greeting_custom, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_location_type.id as location_type_id, civicrm_location_type.name as `location_type`, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.street_number as `street_number`, civicrm_address.street_number_suffix as `street_number_suffix`, civicrm_address.street_name as `street_name`, civicrm_address.street_unit as `street_unit`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.name as `address_name`, civicrm_address.master_id as `master_id`, civicrm_address.county_id as county_id, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_phone.phone_ext as `phone_ext`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_email.is_bulkmail as `is_bulkmail`, civicrm_email.signature_text as `signature_text`, civicrm_email.signature_html as `signature_html`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as `im_provider`, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_openid.id as openid_id, civicrm_openid.openid as `openid`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`, civicrm_website.id as website_id, civicrm_website.url as `url`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_group.title)) as groups, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_tag.name)) as tags, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_note.note)) as notes FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_openid ON ( civicrm_openid.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_openid.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type ON civicrm_address.location_type_id = civicrm_location_type.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact ON civicrm_group_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added' LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache ON civicrm_group_contact_cache.contact_id = contact_a.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group ON (civicrm_group.id = civicrm_group_contact.group_id OR civicrm_group.id = civicrm_group_contact_cache.group_id) LEFT JOIN civicrm_entity_tag ON ( civicrm_entity_tag.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND civicrm_entity_tag.entity_id = contact_a.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_note ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-125` ON (contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact-125`.contact_id AND `civicrm_group_contact-125`.status IN ('Added')) LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125`.contact_id LEFT JOIN civicrm_tag ON civicrm_entity_tag.tag_id = civicrm_tag.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_website ON contact_a.id = civicrm_website.contact_id WHERE ( ( ( `civicrm_group_contact-125`.group_id IN ( 125 ) ) OR ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125`.group_id IN ("125") ) ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.is_deleted != 1 GROUP BY contact_a.id ORDER BY sort_name asc, contact_a.id LIMIT 0, 10000 [nativecode=126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7ae3_0.MYI'; try to repair it] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.hash as `hash`, contact_a.source as `contact_source`, contact_a.first_name as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code as `sic_code`, contact_a.user_unique_id as `user_unique_id`, contact_a.employer_id as `current_employer_id`, contact_a.is_deleted as `contact_is_deleted`, contact_a.created_date as `created_date`, contact_a.modified_date as `modified_date`, contact_a.addressee_id as addressee_id, contact_a.addressee_display as addressee_display, contact_a.addressee_custom as addressee_custom, contact_a.email_greeting_id as email_greeting_id, contact_a.email_greeting_display as email_greeting_display, contact_a.email_greeting_custom as email_greeting_custom, contact_a.postal_greeting_id as postal_greeting_id, contact_a.postal_greeting_display as postal_greeting_display, contact_a.postal_greeting_custom as postal_greeting_custom, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_location_type.id as location_type_id, civicrm_location_type.name as `location_type`, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.street_number as `street_number`, civicrm_address.street_number_suffix as `street_number_suffix`, civicrm_address.street_name as `street_name`, civicrm_address.street_unit as `street_unit`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.name as `address_name`, civicrm_address.master_id as `master_id`, civicrm_address.county_id as county_id, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_phone.phone_ext as `phone_ext`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_email.is_bulkmail as `is_bulkmail`, civicrm_email.signature_text as `signature_text`, civicrm_email.signature_html as `signature_html`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as `im_provider`, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_openid.id as openid_id, civicrm_openid.openid as `openid`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`, civicrm_website.id as website_id, civicrm_website.url as `url`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_group.title)) as groups, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_tag.name)) as tags, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_note.note)) as notes FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_openid ON ( civicrm_openid.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_openid.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type ON civicrm_address.location_type_id = civicrm_location_type.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact ON civicrm_group_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added' LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache ON civicrm_group_contact_cache.contact_id = contact_a.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group ON (civicrm_group.id = civicrm_group_contact.group_id OR civicrm_group.id = civicrm_group_contact_cache.group_id) LEFT JOIN civicrm_entity_tag ON ( civicrm_entity_tag.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND civicrm_entity_tag.entity_id = contact_a.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_note ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-125` ON (contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact-125`.contact_id AND `civicrm_group_contact-125`.status IN ('Added')) LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125`.contact_id LEFT JOIN civicrm_tag ON civicrm_entity_tag.tag_id = civicrm_tag.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_website ON contact_a.id = civicrm_website.contact_id WHERE ( ( ( `civicrm_group_contact-125`.group_id IN ( 125 ) ) OR ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125`.group_id IN ("125") ) ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.is_deleted != 1 GROUP BY contact_a.id ORDER BY sort_name asc, contact_a.id LIMIT 0, 10000 [nativecode=126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7ae3_0.MYI'; try to repair it] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.hash as `hash`, contact_a.source as `contact_source`, contact_a.first_name as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code as `sic_code`, contact_a.user_unique_id as `user_unique_id`, contact_a.employer_id as `current_employer_id`, contact_a.is_deleted as `contact_is_deleted`, contact_a.created_date as `created_date`, contact_a.modified_date as `modified_date`, contact_a.addressee_id as addressee_id, contact_a.addressee_display as addressee_display, contact_a.addressee_custom as addressee_custom, contact_a.email_greeting_id as email_greeting_id, contact_a.email_greeting_display as email_greeting_display, contact_a.email_greeting_custom as email_greeting_custom, contact_a.postal_greeting_id as postal_greeting_id, contact_a.postal_greeting_display as postal_greeting_display, contact_a.postal_greeting_custom as postal_greeting_custom, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_location_type.id as location_type_id, civicrm_location_type.name as `location_type`, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.street_number as `street_number`, civicrm_address.street_number_suffix as `street_number_suffix`, civicrm_address.street_name as `street_name`, civicrm_address.street_unit as `street_unit`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.name as `address_name`, civicrm_address.master_id as `master_id`, civicrm_address.county_id as county_id, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_phone.phone_ext as `phone_ext`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_email.is_bulkmail as `is_bulkmail`, civicrm_email.signature_text as `signature_text`, civicrm_email.signature_html as `signature_html`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as `im_provider`, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_openid.id as openid_id, civicrm_openid.openid as `openid`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`, civicrm_website.id as website_id, civicrm_website.url as `url`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_group.title)) as groups, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_tag.name)) as tags, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(civicrm_note.note)) as notes FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_openid ON ( civicrm_openid.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_openid.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type ON civicrm_address.location_type_id = civicrm_location_type.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact ON civicrm_group_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added' LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache ON civicrm_group_contact_cache.contact_id = contact_a.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group ON (civicrm_group.id = civicrm_group_contact.group_id OR civicrm_group.id = civicrm_group_contact_cache.group_id) LEFT JOIN civicrm_entity_tag ON ( civicrm_entity_tag.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND civicrm_entity_tag.entity_id = contact_a.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_note ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-125` ON (contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact-125`.contact_id AND `civicrm_group_contact-125`.status IN ('Added')) LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125`.contact_id LEFT JOIN civicrm_tag ON civicrm_entity_tag.tag_id = civicrm_tag.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_website ON contact_a.id = civicrm_website.contact_id WHERE ( ( ( `civicrm_group_contact-125`.group_id IN ( 125 ) ) OR ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_125`.group_id IN ("125") ) ) ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.is_deleted != 1 GROUP BY contact_a.id ORDER BY sort_name asc, contact_a.id LIMIT 0, 10000 [nativecode=126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7ae3_0.MYI'; try to repair it]"] )
Severity    debug
```

And this in backtrace:

```
$backTrace = #0 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(235): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error)) #2 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error)) #3 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #4 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #5 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...", "DB_Error", TRUE) #6 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7ae3_0.MYI'; try to repair it") #7 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError() #8 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #9 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #10 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #11 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #12 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1192): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...", TRUE) #13 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php(673): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`,...") #14 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Export/Form/Select.php(434): CRM_Export_BAO_Export::exportComponents(TRUE, (Array:0), (Array:3), "sort_name asc", NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, "civicrm_task_action_temp_b18a86a4753f6c9a7d554f52e40be414_8338", 0, 1, (Array:11), 1) #15 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(345): CRM_Export_Form_Select->postProcess() #16 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(164): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess() #17 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Export_Form_Select), "next", "Next") #18 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Export_Form_Select), "next") #19 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Export_Form_Select), "next") #20 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next") #21 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), (Array:0)) #22 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13)) #23 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3)) #24 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3)) #25 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("group", "search") #26 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2)) #27 /home/evanstonsymph/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #28 {main}
Severity    debug
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are hitting is: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_7ae3_0.MYI'; try to repair it

A google search suggests you don't have enough space in /tmp for it to fully create the temp table.